# onclick condition between to alert messages

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, alert

How can I make the 2nd alert appear by clicking the 1st alert?

```
<button> onclick="single()"></button>

<script>
  var single = 'Just \'single\' quotes';
    alert(single);
</script>

<script>
  var double = "Just \"double\" quotes";
  alert(double);
</script>
```

Comment: Stop trying to develop malicious applications

Comment: You can't, for very good reasons.

Comment: Can someone explain me what's going on here ?

Comment: What is this: <button> onclick="single()"></button>

Comment: 'double' is a reserved word in JS (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) , and so can't be used as a  variable name, and you haven't got a 'single()' function. But: alert(d());function d() {alert('hi');}. Is the desired effect attack or defense?

Comment: @MarcoPrins I'm a beginner just trying to understand what the book is telling me

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try this?

```html
<button onclick="single(); double();"></button>
```

Offcource you should create this functions with alerts first.